# crispy forms creating fields with id of other form

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to add some JS to my password field, so I need its ID. I am getting error:
[image: error]
It makes sense if I look into HTML with inspect. There are 2 identical password fields, but in my forms, I am adding ID to only one of them.
Forms:

```py
class CustomUserSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter email'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter password', 'id': 'password-input'}))
     
    
class CustomUserLogInForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter email'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter password'}))
```

HTML:

```html
<!-- LOG IN FORM -->
  <div class="form-group log-in-form" id="log-in-form">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" id="close-log-in" aria-label="Close"></button>
    <form method="POST" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <h1>Log in</h1>
      {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
      {{ form.password1|as_crispy_field }}
      <input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember me<br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn log-in-btn" id="log-in-btn">Log in</button>
      <p>Forgot password? <a href="#">Reset</a></p>
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'sign_up' %}" class="btn sign-up-btn">Sign up</a>
  </div>

  {% block content %}

  {% endblock %}
```

Other HTML (diffrent view, but I am inheriting template):

```html
{% block content %}

<div class="form-group sign-up-form container-fluid">
  <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Sign up</h1>
    {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}  
    {{ form.password1|as_crispy_field }}
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-password">Show Password<br>
    {{ form.nick|as_crispy_field }}
    <p id="sign-up-requirements">Password too short</p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn log-in-btn">Sign up</button>
    * required field
  </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Now I am getting around the problem by using

```js
getElementsByClassName('...')[1]
```

but it is stupid solution and I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the prefix option when you are instantiating your forms.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms

```
sign_up_form = CustomUserSignUpForm(prefix='signup')
```

each field will get the prefix after the 'id'. So "id_signup-email" or similar will be generated.